# Double clicking error with JQuery and ASP MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Good morning!
I have a checkbox in my Razor and it shows a div with a datepicker when the check box is checked.
My error is when I double click the checkbox shows the div with the datepicker when is not checked (Do the opposite of what I need).

Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SupHUBZoneCertified, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
      <div class="col-md-8">
           <div class="checkbox" id="cb1">
               <label>
                  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SupHUBZoneCertified)
                  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SupHUBZoneCertified, "HUB Zone Certified:")
               </label>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group" id="dateCb1" style="display:none">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SupCategoryHUBZoneDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
      <div class="col-md-8">
           @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SupCategoryHUBZoneDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker" } })
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SupCategoryHUBZoneDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
       </div>
  </div>
```

and my javascript:

```
$("#cb1").click(function () {
    $("#dateCb1").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

[image: one click works fine]

[image: double click and do the opposite of what I need]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all I found the error, so basically I can't use the #cb1 as the checkbox ID because I need to use the ID of the input.
The ID for the input is self generated in ASP MVC and use the name declared in the MVC model.

So the code would be

```
 $("#SupHUBZoneCertified").click(function () {
    $("#dateCb1").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

I found the input class name using "Inspect Element in Internet Explorer"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're using a jQuery UI datepicker, I can't see the `toggle` method in the [api docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

There are only `show` and `hide` methods.

So you should modify your code:

```
$("#cb1").click(function () {
    var action = this.checked ? "show" : "hide";
    $("#dateCb1").datepicker(action);
    $("#dateCb1").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Comment: Thank you Vsevolod indeed I am using a jQuery UI datepicker however I am not showing or hiding the datepicker. I am showing and hiding a div with the label and the datepicker.

Comment: @CesarD aha, I see that, try combining hiding the dive and closing the datepicker. I've modified my answer

Comment: Thank you Vsevolod your code works fine and mine too. If I check shows the div and if I uncheck it doesn't however If I double click show the div when is unchecked and hide the div when is checked.